# Cannot seem to correctly identify a CSS/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, What I want to do is create a good looking underline under the active tab, but I cannot seem to tag the class specifically enough, of course I am using bootstrap, I want to use a HR because i do not know how to change the width and margin of a text-decoration or identify a element such as border-bottom.

HTML CODE

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blogStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid"
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-pills">
        <li><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE

```
/* navbar */
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #a300cc;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-top:0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    height:60px;

 }
/* Title */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a .nav-link .active {
    font-size:10px;
}

a.nav-link.active {
    font-size:100px;
}


/* Link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: white;
    font-size:19px;

}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color:  #a300cc;

}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: #D5D5D5;
}
/* Caret */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: #777;
    border-bottom-color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: white;
}

a.nav-link.active {
    font-size:100px;
}
```

As you can see, I have already tried to test the a.nav-link.active, but still did not work

Comment: Your div class container-fluid needs a closing bracket

Comment: “I do not know how to change the width and margin of a text-decoration or identify a element such as border bottom” - are you asking how to implement border bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your CSS with this CSS.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #777;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a.nav-link.active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the developer tools to see which CSS selector overrides your a.nav-link.active selector.

In this case it is this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a
```

Your selector will be specific enough If you change it to this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.nav-link.active
```

Then you can add styling for the bottom border.

Answer (score 0):

Check closing tag of `ul`

You can use `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a.active` for active menu

```css
/* navbar */

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #a300cc;
  border-color: #E7E7E7;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-top: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  height: 60px;
}


/* Title */

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a .nav-link .active {
  font-size: 10px;
}

a.nav-link.active {
  font-size: 100px;
}


/* Link */

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: white;
  background-color: #a300cc;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: white;
  background-color: #D5D5D5;
}


/* Caret */

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret {
  border-top-color: #777;
  border-bottom-color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-pills">
        <li><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```